# PayPal Sandbox not receiving IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have been trying today with my PayPal Sandbox adaptive payments.
I'm not getting IPN back from PayPal. Any issues on PayPal side. Please note that site uses HTTPS/TLS 1.2